# AWS kinesis SDK in background script chrome extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome-extension, amazon-kinesis

I need to create a camera stream through WEBRTC to Amazon AWS Kinesis. I am currently accessing the user's camera from the background script.

Is it possible to use the AWS SDK in the background script or what alternatives would you recommend?

The issue is that the stream needs to be constant so if it is in a content script it would have to be injected into a tab and record from there instead and potentially load the AWS SDK from there.

Ideally I would like to access those services from a background script which will stay active the whole time, is this possible?

Resources: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js#installing

Will Update question if I have any updates.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found was to create a `background.html` and add the `sdk` on top of the `background.js`.